# Fabric.js - Change Rectangle Fill

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I am working on a application that uses [Fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/docs/symbols/fabric.Object.html).

I need to be able to change the **fill** of the **rectangle** that I put up as background.

I use `canvas.getActiveObject()` to change the fill of the rectangle. Unfortunately I cant seem to find a method that will change the Fill of the rectangle.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Text Rendering Example</title>
    <script src="fabric.js"></script>  
    <script src="canvas2image.js"></script>
    <script src="base64.js"></script>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="600" style="border:1px solid #000000"></canvas>
    
    
    
    <form name = "boxForm" onsubmit="addBox()">
        Width: <input type="text" name="firstname" /><br />
        Text: <input id="text-control" type="text" name="textString" />
        Text Color: <input id="text-color" type="text" value = "#FF0000" name="textColor" />
        Background Color: <input id="background-color" type="text" value = "#333333" name="backgroundColor" />
    </form> 
    
    <button onclick="addBox()">Background</button>
    
    <button onclick="addText()">Add Text</button>
    
    <!--button onclick="updateControls()">Edit Text</button-->
    
    <button onclick="saveImage()">File</button>

    <script type="text/javascript" >
    
        var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');       
        
        var $ = function(id){return document.getElementById(id)};
      
        var textArray = new Array();
        
        var textControl = $('text-control');        
        var textColor = $('text-color');
        var backgroundColor = $('background-color');
      
        function addBox()
        {       
            var rect = new fabric.Rect({
            width: 1000,
            height: 600,
            top: 300,
            left: 500,
            fill: 'rgba(51,51,51,1)',
            draggable: false
            });
            rect.lockMovementX = true;
            rect.lockMovementY = true; 
            rect.lockUniScaling = true; 
            rect.lockRotation = true; 

            canvas.add(rect);
        }

        function addText()
        {
            var content = document.boxForm.textString.value;
            var color = document.boxForm.textColor.value;
            
            text = new fabric.Text(content, {               
                left: 100, 
                top: 100,
                fill: color
            });
            text.lockUniScaling = true; 
            text.lockRotation = true;

            //textArrayAdd(text);   
                
            canvas.add(text);
        }
        
        textControl.onchange = function() {
            canvas.getActiveObject().setText(this.value);
            canvas.renderAll();
        };
        
        textColor.onchange = function() {
            canvas.getActiveObject().setColor(this.value);
            canvas.renderAll();
        };
        
        /*----This is where I change the color of the Rectangle-----*/

        backgroundColor.onchange = function() {         
            canvas.getActiveObject().fillRect( 20, 100, 100, 50 );
            canvas.renderAll();
        };

        /*----This is where I change the color of the Rectangle-----*/

        
        /*function textArrayAdd(obj)
        {
            textArray.push(obj);
        }*/
        
        function updateControls() {         
            textControl.value = canvas.getActiveObject().getText();
        }
        
        canvas.on({
            'object:selected': updateControls,
        });
                
        /*var strDataURI = canvas.toDataURL('image/png'); 
        
        function saveImage()
        {           
            Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas); 
        }*/
        
        
    </script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Any ideas on how to change it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Fixed the problem by using basic set method of fabric:

```
backgroundColor.onchange = function() {         
    canvas.getActiveObject().set("fill", this.value);
    canvas.renderAll();
};
```

Answer (score 2):

tri this the easy and simple code by fabrics documentation

```
var activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject();
        activeObject.fill = 'your color code value';
        canvas.renderAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function addBox()
        {       
            var rect = new fabric.Rect({
            width: 1000,
            height: 600,
            top: 300,
            left: 500,
            fill: ' ',
            draggable: false
            });
            rect.lockMovementX = true;
            rect.lockMovementY = true; 
            rect.lockUniScaling = true; 
            rect.lockRotation = true; 

            canvas.add(rect);
        }

make your fill null and if you want to have a border 
use strokeWidth: 3, stroke: "color"
```